# Дизайн прикладных программ

Tags: c#, java, css

У меня вопрос: 
есть ли что-нибудь такое, как CSS, но для дизайна десктопных программ?
Или какие технологии используют для написания дизайна вроде этого (нестандартного для Windows):
http://cdn.appstorm.net/windows.appstorm.net/files/2011/04/sshot-2011-4-19-490.png
Извиняюсь, может плохо объяснил, надеюсь, кто-то поймет мой вопрос)

Comment: "такое как CSS" - это WPF с его XAML.

Answer (score 2):

Вам смотреть в сторону WPF XAML. Создавать можно в Microsoft Expression Blend или Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 >=

Comment: Вы хотели сказать, 2008?

Comment: Ну, начиная с 2012, значительно улучшились инструменты для дизайна. Не вижу смысла использовать более старые версии для этой цели